# How to format timestamp in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have this timestamp created_at

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('M d, Y h:i:s');
}
```

How can I format this like `Oct 9, 2021 at 1:23 PM` with an `at` string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the string by escaping the characters:

```
return Carbon::parse($value)->format('M d, Y \a\t H:i');
```

Comment: Oh like Josh Alecyan commented on another answer , you don't need to carbon parse the value (it is already a Carbon date)

Answer (score 3):

you can chain format as you need:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
  
     return $value->format('M d, Y ').' at '.$value->format('h:i:s');
}
```

Comment: Not a bad solution

Comment: All Nice, but this line is  not needed $value=Carbon::parse($value);

Answer (score 0):

```
   return Carbon::parse($value)->format('M d, Y').' at '.Carbon::parse($value)->format('g:i A');
```

Comment: It should be in this format 'Oct 9, 2021 at 1:23 PM'